# ChartJs Расположить 2 колонки друг на друге

Tags: angular, chart.js

---

Пожалуйста, помогите реализовать таблицу используя библиотеку ChartJs подобным образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно меня интерересует наложение красного bara на синий bar.

Comment: Или объясните какие свойства отвечают за эту реализацию